# R fast way to read values from a matrix?

Tags: r

I wish to read values as fast as possible from a matrix (or a vector).

The standard way would be as follows:

```
# defining the matrix
x = matrix(runif(100), nrow=10)
# reading one value
x[2,3]
```

I have tried using a data.table with an index, but it looks a lot slower:

```
x2 = as.data.table(x)
x2$idx = 1:10
setkey(x2, idx)
x2

x[2,3]
x2[2,3, with=F]
# we verify it is the same value

microbenchmark(x[2,3], x2[2,3, with=F])
Unit: nanoseconds
               expr    min     lq     mean median     uq    max neval
            x[2, 3]    132    157    479.9    504    677   2811   100
 x2[2, 3, with = F] 181007 185055 200142.2 188007 197573 441153   100
```

Is there any way to do faster than the base matrix read?

Comment: I fear not. R is not designed for such performance goals (at least its base goal was not this). But here is a thing one could try: if reading a single value is quite quicker with a base read than with a data.table read, could you benchmark the reading of multiple values (let's say something like 10,000) using the two methods? I think that you could see the interest of the data.table index by handling more massive data.

Comment: For data.table, extracting the vector and then subsetting can be faster. ```dt[["V3"]][2]``` - I'm not at my computer to test. I'd also look into whether a key helps for simple subsetting by row number. I would doubt it.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify my comment, the extraction can be faster than other data.table methods. I highly doubt anything would be faster than matrix subsetting.

Comment: The syntax `x[9][505:605]` seems to be consistently faster than `x[505:605, 9]` for extracting multiple values, but consistently slower when extracting single values, i.e. `x[9][505]` vs. `x[505, 9]`.

Comment: @gersht interesting. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no faster way to do a matrix read than `matr[i, j]`.

1. If you have a vector, extracting the equivalent element can be slightly faster.
2. If you have a data.table, do `dt[['V3']][2]`. `dt[2,3]` is super slow.
3. If you have a data.frame, do `df[['V3']][2]`.

Your example with 10,000,000 values in 10 rows (i.e., 1,000,000 columns)

```
Unit: nanoseconds
          expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
      vect[22]        100        900       1380       1250       2000       2900    10

       x[2, 3]        100        200       1130       1500       1700       2300    10
       x[[22]]        600       1000       1620       1600       1700       4400    10

      dt[2, 3] 1120103100 1121659900 1132672490 1121957850 1123820200 1226030600    10
     dt[2, V3] 1183598600 1185074800 1204766740 1188306650 1220468900 1262510200    10
 dt[["V3"]][2]       8900      16800      32950      39850      43200      44400    10

      df[2, 3]    7851400    7867500    8753220    8730250    9547200   10022700    10
 df[["V3"]][2]       8100      11500      20830      16150      32700      36000    10
```

Your example with 10,000,000 rows and 10 columns:

```
Unit: nanoseconds
          expr    min     lq   mean median     uq      max neval
      vect[22]    100    300    508    400    600     2000   100

       x[2, 3]    200    300    591    500    800     2600   100
       x[[22]]    200    500    727    600    900     1900   100

      dt[2, 3] 280800 288700 314736 295350 325200   509700   100
     dt[2, V3] 495700 505950 910938 522750 560700 37038500   100
 dt[["V3"]][2]   8200   9200  12048  11350  13100    23200   100

      df[2, 3]  20600  23100  29587  28700  32950    68100   100
 df[["V3"]][2]   7400   8300  11310  10500  12550    24100   100
```

Your example with 100 rows:

```
Unit: nanoseconds
          expr    min     lq   mean median     uq    max neval
      vect[22]      0    300    416    300    500   1100   100

       x[2, 3]    100    300    542    450    800   1500   100
       x[[22]]    100    400    654    600    800   1400   100

      dt[2, 3] 256200 262000 270385 264850 268950 410100   100
     dt[2, V3] 432000 439750 457196 443900 462200 617900   100
 dt[["V3"]][2]   7800   8700  10965  10350  11400  23500   100

      df[2, 3]  16600  18450  23580  22600  27300  81800   100
 df[["V3"]][2]   7100   7850   9781   9400  10300  15100   100
```

**Edit:** Data:

```
library(data.table)

set.seed(1)

vect <- runif(1E7)
x <- matrix(vect, ncol = 10)
df <- as.data.frame(x)
dt <- as.data.table(x)

vect[22];x[2,3];x[[22]];dt[2, 3]; df[2, 3]
```